# Mutiple uniqueid for single call in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip

I have installed asterisk 11 and configured the voip account.And am originate the call

If the call answered am sending to `context ,s,1`

If the call not answering am sending to `context,failed,1`

Issue : When the originated call in answered am getting single entry in CDR, but when the call is not answered or busy am getting two CDR entries with different unique ids.

Below is the command I am using to originate:

```
Action: Originate
CallerID:+911233211233
WaitTime: 30
Channel: SIP/Voip/mynumber
Context: asteriskdial
Exten: s
Priority: 1
```

example :I am originating a call and enduser rejected the call and the call came `context asteriskdial,failed,1`.  But when I have `NoOp` the unique id in the context am getting different unique id and disposition as answered of the Busy call. And in CDR there are two entry one with actiual dial entry with proper entry and second one as wrong dispositions.

Can any one help on this??

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueid is different on every different leg.

If you want not see unanswered calls, check cdr.conf unanswered= param.